# socket.io: Cross-Origin Request Blocked on Firefox

Tags: node.js, firefox, socket.io, cross-domain

I'm running a nodejs socket.io server on a raspberry pi, and a socket.io web client on Firefox.

But Firefox keeps giving me a Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Same Origin Policy Error).

```
    // nodeJS Server:
    var app = require('express')();
    var cors = require('cors');
    app.use(cors({origin: '*:*'}));
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    server.listen(3000);

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('announcements', { message: 'A new user jas joined!' });
    });
    

    //JS Browser client:
    const socket = io('ws://<INSERT_MY_EXTERNAL_IP>:3000');

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.send('Hello!');
    });
```

I've also tried: io.origins(...), io.set("origin", ...), but those keep saying the functions **origins** and **set** are undefined.

Not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a `cors` prop when you initialize the server socket.

Pass in a config object with `cors` set to `true`, eg. `cors: true` or `cors: { origin: '*' }`.

Read more about that [here](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#CORS-handling).

**In action (only tested in LAN):**

client.js

```
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');
socket.on('testing', res => { console.log(res) });
```

server.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const opts = { cors: { origin: '*' } }
const io = require('socket.io')(server, opts)

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`Client connected (id=${socket.id})`)

  socket.emit('testing', 123)

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Client disconnected (id=${socket.id})`)
  })
});

(
  port => server.listen(
    port, 
    () => console.log(`Express server running on port ${port}`)
  )
)(3000)
```

Comment: I've tried this. The problem is, I'm not connecting to localhost, I'm connecting to an external IP address.

I still get the Cross-Origin domain error.

Comment: Are you sure you're not tripping up on syntax? socket.io intro'd some breaking changes _yesterday_, so it may be worth double-checking your code while referencing: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/releases.

Comment: There are no syntax errors. I believe this has to do with that I'm connecting to an external IP address, but the machine I'm connecting to happens to be on my home network too. So when I'm at home, I get the CORS (Cross-Origin domain error).

Also I've tried version 3.0.0 and 2.3.0 of socket.io.